# Not enough computer space when installing ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 18.04, live-usb

When I try to install Ubuntu it says I don't have enough space on my computer.

Also when I try to boot from USB it says there is no USB on the system, so I end up booting from linpus lite. I created a bootable USB using Rufus.

[image: my df] 
[image: gparted] 
[image: windows partitioning]

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Did I not allocate enough space on my drive or did am I not supposed to boot from linpus lite.

Comment: did you set usb drive to be first boot device in your bios?

Comment: please note, for pure text output, it's best to paste the text into your question and format it as code

Comment: Is the disk partitioning msdos (yes even with an EFI partition)?  There's a max of four primary partitions in that case, so you'd have to make a extended partition to hold logical partitions.

Comment: @Zandew - try Xubuntu or Lubuntu - try to avoid Gnome or to avoid KDE - instead choose xfce as window manager...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore we’re sorry, Ask Ubuntu is not a forum but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the space on your USB Live Boot which is 7 GB.

In `gparted` you need to look at the unallocated partition after you Windows C drive. Here in your unallocated partition you have 103 GB free.

Select the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" and you should have no problem pointing the installer to the 103 GB empty partition.

If you need more pointers follow this Q&A: [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069)